# calculate field (prefer Python)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have an attribute field with string data values (e.g. "P0001","C3492","00123"). I need to replace them so that they're all unique and begin with "W" followed by digits totaling 5 characters.

I thought perhaps ranking may work but not sure how to rank a string. The resulting output will look like ("W0001","W0002","W0003"). I prefer a Python solution in the field calculator but can also use VB.

Comment: Even though you have been a user of the site for over a year I note that you have not yet  taken its 2-minute [Tour] which is designed to introduce all users to its protocols.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) (in this case your current expression and code block) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, I would suggest using a python generator in combination with an [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) First you would define your generator function. Something like this:

```
def get_unique_identifier(n):
    num = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        while num < n:
            yield 'W{0:04}'.format(num)
            num += 1
```

Then you can use an `update cursor` like this to update the proper field with the value generated by the function/generator above:

```
in_feature_class = r'C:\path_to_data\your_data.shp'
field_to_update = 'the_field'
number_of_records = arcpy.GetCount_management(in_feature_class)
unique_values = get_unique_identifier(number_of_records)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_feature_class, field_to_update) as u_cur:
    for row in u_cur:
        row[0] = unique_values.next()
        u_cur.updateRow(row)
```

This is a quick go and there are certainly things that could be improved upon. If the order in which these fields are updated matters you may want to utilize an `ORDER BY` field in the `sql_clause` when creating your update cursor so that you update the values in the sorted order that you want. However this should get you on your way.

Comment: Instead of a function, you could also do `for i,row in enumerate(u_cur):...u_cur.update('W{0:04}'.format(i))` -- Exact same thing and you can define the start value as well.